# How to change an observable http request to promise request

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, promise, angular-promise

This is my service file
[image: This is my service file]
This is my components ts file
[image: This is my components ts file]
And these are response models
[image: List response model]
[image: Response model]

I am having issues with displaying the data I'm fetching through an Observable-based service in my TypeScript file for the component due to its asynchronous nature. From what I've learned, I need to convert my service to a Promise-based structure, but I'm having trouble implementing the responseModel that Observable provides in a Promise-based structure. I would appreciate your help.
These are outputs
[image]

Comment: I suggest continue with observables they are building blocks of angular app. You just need to subscribe or use the async pipe to get the data.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RxJS 7.8.0, I would recommend using [lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom)

Example:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { lastValueFrom, take } from 'rxjs';

class YourService {

  constructor(
    private readonly httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  async yourFunction(): Promise<YourTypeOrInterface> {
    const request$ = this.httpClient.get(yourUrl).pipe(take(1));

    return await lastValueFrom<YourTypeOrInterface>(request$);
  }

}
```

`.toPromise()` is deprecated and will be removed completely in RxJS 8.

Answer (score -2):

Observables have a `.toPromise()` method on them

```js
const response = await this.currencyService.getAllByDate(...).toPromise()
```

EDIT
Your call stack needs to be async the whole way down too

```js
async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.getAllByDate();
    ...
}

async getAllByDate() {
    let date;
    if (this.selectedDate == null) {
        date = new Date(Date.now()).setHours(3,0,0,0);
    } else {
        date = new Date(this.selectedDate).setHours(3,0,0,0);
    }

    const response = await this.currencyService.getAllByDate(new Date(date)).toPromise();

    if (response && isArray(response.data)) {
        this.currencies = response.data;
        this.currencies.push(newCurrency);
    }
}
```

UPDATE
Since `toPromise()` is being deprecated if you insist on using promises, you'll have to roll your own in future versions

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.currencyService.getAllByDate(...)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe({ complete: resolve, error: reject })
});

const response = await promise;
```

Comment: Actually I did it like this
async getAllByDate() {
    let date;
    if (this.selectedDate == null) {
      date = new Date(Date.now()).setHours(3,0,0,0);
    } else {
      date = new Date(this.selectedDate).setHours(3,0,0,0);
    }
    const response = await this.currencyService.getAllByDate(new Date(date)).toPromise();
    this.currencies = response.data;
    this.currencies.push(newCurrency);
  }
but ı got this error in 'response'
const response: ListResponseModel<Currency> | undefined
'response' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

Comment: It sounds like your initial problem may be the response isn't coming through as you'd expect

Comment: I added the log images, the data is coming

Comment: The async call needs to be all the way down (your ngOnInit needs to be async too), I've updated my answer

Comment: i fixed it as you did but i still get the same error "'response' is possibly 'undefined'."

Comment: Is this a runtime error or compiler error?

Comment: It is compiler error

Comment: this.currencies = response?.data || []    
i did like this and it solved for now. Thanks for helping

Comment: @AhmetAltintas Further updated the answer to add an array check