# Unresolved promise while redirecting to new page

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, angular-httpclient

My web server could return a custom exception wrapped in a `400 Bad Request` object. On the client-side (Angular 9), I have something like this:

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
   this.http.post(...).subscribe(data => {
      // ...
      resolve(true);
   }, err => {
      // this is the code that will be executed (400 Bad Request is returned from the server)
      this.myService.handleHttpError(err); // prints something friendly to the user; redirects to the previous page
      // notice I don't resolve the Promise
   })
})
```

If I resolve the Promise inside the error part, some methods from the method caller are executed (I don't want them to execute). If I don't resolve the Promise it fixes this issue. Do I need to worry about memory & resource leaks or something else?

Comment: You probably should reject the promise then?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75642287/how-to-change-an-observable-http-request-to-promise-request?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top I'm not quite willing to mjolnir this...

Comment: Also, like @Jared wrote, you should definitely use `lastValueFrom` instead of constructing your own `new Promise` (and mixing the conversion logic with your result handling)